# JBOSS 7,2 with open JDK and having spring boot war is shutdown when JVM restart

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, ehcache, executor

Having Jboss 7.2 and open JDK 1.8  with spring boot(spring boot and  ehcache, Executor) ,

when server is  active able to deploy the spring boot wars  successfully and application is in Active state,

but when we restart the Jboss 7.2  JVM , application and JVM is going down and  no proper info in server.log

need to fix this  JVM restart issue

Comment: how do you restart Jboss?

Comment: Start.sh in bin directory using JBOSS user